# Why bounded solution and convergence imply a stability for nonlinear finite difference scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

I have been review the finite difference for long wave family equation (RLW, Rosenau-kawahara, etc) and see that the boundedness and convergence always imply the stability of the proposed difference scheme

The list of some reviewed paper are

1. Hu, Jinsong, et al. "Two conservative difference schemes for Rosenau-Kawahara equation." Advances in Mathematical Physics 2014 (2014).
2. Pan, Xintian, Kelong Zheng, and Luming Zhang. "Finite difference discretization of the Rosenau-RLW equation." Applicable Analysis 92.12 (2013): 2578-2589.

Comment: You might want to provide a little more information?

Comment: Assume that the proposed scheme called difference schemeA. They can prove that the solution $u$ of the schemeA is bounded in sense of $\Vert \cdot\Vert_{\infty}$ and then they conclude that the solution schemeA is stable